# Equations with negative exponents

Tags: roots

This may be standard matter, but how an equation of the form $a x + b + c x^{-1} = 0$ is solved?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ax+b+cx^{-1}=0\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} x\ne 0\\ \frac{ax^2+bx+c}{x}=0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases} x\ne 0\\ ax^2+bx+c=0\end{cases}$$

and so forth. First step is the same for inequations as well, but for those you would have to evaluate the sign of the whole fraction, not just the numerator.

*Added:* It might be a matter of debate what happens for $c=0$ and, specifically, if for $c=0$ the quantity $cx^{-1}$ is to be interpreted as the constant $0$ function or as $0$ multiplied by the inverse of $x$: i.e. as if I asked a machine that computes according to PEDMAS to evaluate in $x=0$, $c=0$ and $a,b=\text{something}$ the expression $ax+b+cx^{-1}$, under the additional hypothesis that the machine returns an error as soon as it is asked to evaluate a function outside of its domain. My discussion is in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that $x=0$ cannot be a solution (note the negative power). Then multiply throughout by $x$ giving a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $c \neq 0$,

$$a x + b + c x^{-1} = 0 \\
\iff ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$

and solve as you would normally solve a quadratic.

Comment: I can't see any good reason to exclude the case $b=0$.

Comment: Yeah that's true. There's also not reason to exclude the case $a=0$, right?

Comment: I don't, despite it not being a quadratic anymore, but then again when I have parameters I don't exclude any case.

Comment: You mean, you wouldn't exclude the case $c=0$ as well? But OP is probably interested only in $c \neq 0$.

Comment: It's your answer, not mine. :) Personally, I ended up writing about the case $c=0$ than I did of the others.

Comment: I can't be bothered to think about the case $c=0$, and it isn't pertinent to OP's question imo. Let OP decide.